# Why do cvs commands fail for repositories when PATH contains cvs and the files exist?

Tags: bash, git, cvs

I have an old cvs repository on a remote server.  I can successfully ssh to that server.  The repository exists on that server. From one of my client machines I can successfully run the command and it returns the log:

```
cvs -d :ext:userid@remote-host-addr:path-to-cvsrep log
```

On my other client machine, the same exact command gives

```
cvs [log aborted]: cannot get working directory: No such file or directory.
```

On both machines the `PATH` contains the path to the cvs executable in `.bashrc`, and I can ssh from both to the server.  I tried to create a local cvs repository on the failing machine in `/usr/local/cvsrep`, for example.  I tried `cvs -d /usr/local/cvsrep init` and it gives the same error.

I have checked the `PATH` on all machines, version on all machines, and things like `CVSROOT`, and `CVS_SSH` variables.

The only difference I can see is that the OS on the working machine is OS X 10.14.6 and on the one where cvs fails is OS X 10.15 beta 19A558d.  I did a fresh brew install cvs on the failing machine.  Could this be the issue?  OR, is there some other obvious thing I am missing.

I am trying to check these old modules out and then put them into git.

Comment: The error message indicates that a `getcwd()` call failed. Perhaps there's something wrong with the directory structure on the server? Try ssh'ing onto the server and typing `/bin/pwd -P`, then `cd` to the CVS repo directory and `/bin/pwd -P` again. (This bypasses the shell's built-in `pwd` command; that might not be necessary, but see if it makes a difference.)

Comment: I did as you suggested.  The first shows my user directory.  The second shows the user-directory/cvsrep, which is as it should be.  I then created a bash script in my ~/bin directory called check_cvsroot containing echo $CVSROOT and made it executable.  ~/bin is in my PATH as is /usr/local/bin where the cvs executable resides.  Then running ssh server check_cvsroot yielded 'userdir/cvsrep' again as it should. So, ssh'ing to the server sources the .bashrc, creating the PATH and CVSROOT.  But from the remote client cvs log fails to find either cvs or CVSROOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the problem, but don't understand exactly what happened.  I restarted the server where the cvs repository was located and now I have access to it just fine.  I will now proceed to check out projects and then add them to a git repository as that's easier and more reliable these days.